# Get files from local folder through a Web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, html

I have a gridview in an aspx page that needs to show all the xml files from a folder on the client machine. Is there anyway to get the contents of a folder given you have the directory path? I have the below code which works fine (as I am running it from my machine), but Im not sure if that works when the app runs from a server.

WebForm.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="dotImage.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
   <form runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="true" Height="487px" Width="1176px" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
   </asp:GridView>
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

WebForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test data"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test data");
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = di.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo pendingBatch in subDirs)
            {
                if (pendingBatch.Exists && pendingBatch.GetFiles("*.xml").Length > 0)
                {
               //code to add files to a dataset
                }
            }
        }
      //bind dataset to the gridview.
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it on your server? It should work if the server has the same directory structure as your local machine and if your web application process has permissions to access the local files. If you are asking if your application can access local files on your own machine when it is running on a remote server, the answer is no.

Comment: Give it a try on your server. If you encounter problems (e.g. an IOException, zero files found, etc.), let us know what happened and we will try to help.

Comment: Additionally `C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test data` is almost certainly an invalid path. The name of a user should appear between Users and Desktop.

Comment: I edited removed the unsername in the path while putting the code here.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the directory path would be obtained from file path of the file the user selects. I will add an `<input type="file">` in the aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

For security reason, the Web browser can't access client machine file's folder path.